# htaccess rewrite - not rewriting to index.php

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have three web servers on three separate computers. I am trying to install a php application that rewrites all url requests to index.php (front controller pattern). The following .htaccess works on two out of the three web servers:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect everything to the Front Controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^(css|images|files)/ index.php [NC,L]
```

So, when I visit `http://example.com/hithere`, index.php is called and I can then parse the originally requested url (`hithere`) to figure out what controller to send it to.

However, for some unknown reason, the above .htaccess file doesn't work on the third webserver. Instead, when I access `http://example.com/hithere`, I get a 404 not found error in my browser that says this:

```
The requested URL /full/path/to/application/index.php was not found on this server.
```

So, based on the above error, I can tell that it's actually trying to redirect to index.php. But the file that the browser lists in the `/full/path/...` below is actually on my web server - so I have no idea why it can't find it. Could someone please help me and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:** I don't know if something in the httpd.conf could be conflicting, but here are the settings I have in httpd.conf for the directory that this application is in

```
Alias /myapp /full/path/to/my/app
<Directory /full/path/to/my/app>
Order allow,deny
AllowOverride All
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

**Edit 2:** I noticed something peculiar in the Apache logs. It looks Apache is appending index.php, which I am trying to redirect traffic to, to the DocumentRoot:

```
File does not exist: /document/root/full/path/to/my/app/index.php
```

When it should be going to:

```
/full/path/to/my/app/index.php
```

So I basically need to tell htaccess to ignore the document root. I tried this by specifying this in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteBase /full/path/to/my/app/
```

But it's still searching the document root for index.php :/ Is there a way to reset the DocumentRoot or tell htaccess to ignore it when rewriting to index.php? Even when I use the absolute path in the RewriteRule, it still appends it to the document root.

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect everything to the Front Controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule !^(css|images|files)/ /full/path/to/my/app/index.php [NC,L]
```

It doesn't make sense to me... Can someone please help?

Thanks

Comment: Does the third web server have mod_rewrite enabled?

Comment: Does the third web server have AllowOverride set to a sufficient high level for the directory your .htaccess is placed in?

Comment: @faffaffaff yes, httpd.conf file has AllowOverride All. I have edited the question with the relevant httpd.conf settings for this application, maybe it's something in there? Thanks for your help

Comment: Check your apache logs.

Comment: Can you show output of `ls -lZ /full/path/to/application/` ?

Comment: Hey guys, please see the second edit to my question. The issue seems to be with the DocumentRoot, but I still can't figure it out :(

Answer (score 0):

> So, based on the above error, I can tell that it's actually trying to
>   redirect to index.php. But the file that the browser lists in the
>   /full/path/... below is actually on my web server - so I have no idea
>   why it can't find it.

Assuming it's a *nix alike system, you might want to check file permissions and make sure that the webserver has read access to the file.

Comment: I checked the permissions and they are correct. Good idea though

Comment: @jerry What is the operating system on Server? In case of a Linux server, which distro?

Comment: the operating system is CentOs. Also, it looks like the issue is related to the DocumentRoot setting in httpd.conf. Please see the second edit to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to check the `DocumentRoot` parameter in `httpd.conf`
Look for something like this in the file and make sure it's correct. That is also where apache will be getting it from.

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/path/to/whatever"
```

Also I would disable `SELinux` if it's on and you **really** don't need it because it causes weird problems too.

Answer (score 0):

First enable rewrite module in apache by using `$ sudo a2enmod rewrite` then restart web server by `$ sudo systemctl restart apache2`
Put following code in your virtual host.

```
<Directory /var/www/html/your_app_folder>
    Order allow,deny
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

then add following code in your `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```